# How can I run rails console from within ConEmu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, console, rails-console, conemu

I recently started using ConEmu and am developing with RoR. For the life of me I can't figure out how to run the rails console within ConEmu.

Directions anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer.

As it turns out, it had nothing to do with ConEmu. I realized I'd just installed devise and this was where the error was.

I had to update the gem file to use the gem "protected_attributes", then ran "bundle" and everything was working fine.

Here's the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17317119/612812) for more clarity.